# Plotting a vector in 3D space between two points on a ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Sorry in advance if this is a trivial question. I am trying to draw a curve between three points on a globe. I have the math for drawing the curve figured out, what I need help with is figuring out how to find the middle vector of my curve that I want to draw (The curve should start at the earth, go into space, then come back down to another point on the earth). I know the start and end point, I know the vector for where the earths center is and the radius of the earth in the simulation. I also know the middle vector between the start and end points in a straight line. How do I go about finding the point in space at some arbitrary distance from the earths center that is greater than the radius of the sphere? I drew a quick image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Sample image I drew of what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Are you simulating the earth as an ellipsoid? Or a sphere? Is $C$ on the surface?

Comment: I am trying to find a point that resides in "The atmosphere", outside of the surface of the sphere.

Comment: C is within the sphere*. C is the middlepoint between points A and B on the sphere if you drew a straight line between them. I thought knowing this point and the center of the sphere would help in finding a point E that is on the line that is started on D and draws through C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit vector going the direction of $C$ is

$$
\hat{C} = \frac{\bf C}{|{\bf C}|}
$$

To get ${\bf E}$ you just need to scale $\hat{C}$ by the amount you need

$$
{\bf E} = r\hat{C}
$$